# Not getting right output...logic correct

Tags: python, math, python-2.7, logic

My code is giving right results except for balance=3926. Lowest Payment: 370 whereas it should be 360.The program should print lowest monthly payment for given annual interest rate .Given an initial balance, code should compute the balance at the end of the year. we are trying our initial balance with a monthly payment of $10. If there is a balance remaining at the end of the year, we write code that would reset the balance to the initial balance, increase the payment by $10, and try again (using the same code!) to compute the balance at the end of the year, to see if this new payment value is large enough

```
annualInterestRate = 0.2

balance = 3926

monthlyinterestrate = annualInterestRate/12.0

remainingBalance = balance

month = 1
total = 0

payment = 10

def CheckMinimumPayment(payment,balance):

    "Checking if payment is in correct balance"
    while(payment*12 < balance):

        payment += 10
    return payment

payment = CheckMinimumPayment(payment,balance)

while(month <= 12):
    remainingBalance = remainingBalance - payment + (annualInterestRate / 12.0) * (remainingBalance - payment)
    month += 1
    total += payment


payment = CheckMinimumPayment(payment,total+remainingBalance)

print("Lowest Payment: " + str(payment))
```

Comment: And *why* is 360 not correct? What would the calculation be, can you work that out for us?

Comment: When posting, please make sure to put your code into the code block (it's the "{}" button). I'm the second person to fix it for you.

Comment: according to the program the answer is 370 but it should be 360

Comment: @MartijnPieters Given an initial balance, code should compute the balance at the end of the year. we are trying our initial balance with a monthly payment of $10. If there is a balance remaining at the end of the year, we write code that would reset the balance to the initial balance, increase the payment by $10, and try again (using the same code!) to compute the balance at the end of the year, to see if this new payment value is large enough.

Comment: When @ianhales said `{}` he didn't mean around it, he meant the icon available when editing... I've rolled back your post to remove them :)

Comment: @JonClements yea dats ok...but whts wrong with the code?

Comment: @user1437027: You can [edit] to update your question.

Comment: How certain are you that 360 is the correct answer?

Comment: @askewchan because that is the answer. You can compute it.

Comment: @askewchan the same margin of error occurs with balance = 4602. output should be 420 whereas output is coming as 430

Comment: If you allow payment to increase in units of one cent ($0.01), your program outputs $361.25  What is the exact solution?

Comment: @askewchan we are searching for the smallest monthly payment such that we can pay off the entire balance within a year. $10 increment of payment is mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not re-iterating through the interest loop (what you have as `while(month <= 12)`) each time you try a new payment.  Write that loop into a function, and call it each time you try a new payment.  The total owed balance depends on the payment, since a larger payment each month means less interest added each month.  Here's what I used:

```
annualInterestRate = 0.2
init_balance = 3926

monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12.0
init_payment = 10

def owedBalance(payment,balance):
    """ Calculate total owed balance after one year
        given an initial balance and montly payment"""

    for month in range(12):
        balance = (balance - payment) * (monthlyInterestRate + 1)

    return payment*12 + balance

def CheckMinimumPayment(payment,balance):
    "Checking if payment is in correct balance"

    while (payment*12 < owedBalance(payment, balance)):
        payment += 10

    return payment

min_payment = CheckMinimumPayment(init_payment,init_balance)

print("Lowest Payment: {}".format(min_payment))
```